# How to replace AddJwtBearer extension in .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-3.0

I have the following code which compiles and works in .NET Core 2.2:

```
  byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Constants.JWT_SECRET); 
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });
```

In .NET Core 3.0 I am getting the error:

> Error CS1061  'AuthenticationBuilder' does not contain a definition for
>   'AddJwtBearer' and no accessible extension method 'AddJwtBearer'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'AuthenticationBuilder' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

when I look at the MSFT documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.jwtbearerextensions.addjwtbearer?view=aspnetcore-2.2

and try to got to version 3.0,  It seems that this is the last version where this is defined.  How do I migrate AddJwtBearer to Core 3.0?

Comment: share your csproject file

Comment: Did u solve this am having the issue in .net 5 where its saying AddTokenAuthentication does not exist

Comment: solved using accepted answer but that was .net core 3.0  you may need a newer version for net 5, I don't use .net 5

Comment: If you convert from version 2.2 to 3.0
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer -Version 3.0.3

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Like Mert Sayin says, include package [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/), but use **Version 3.0.0**.

Answer (score 18):

You must include [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/) package to your project, with version 3.0.0 for Core 3.0 and above.

Comment: Did you use `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;` in top?

Comment: yes I do,  I don't think it is so simple since the MSFT documentation clearly states that this method does not exist in 3.0.  I think there may be some way to use Dependency Injection in startup to add the JwtBearer but I haven't been able to find on internet.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

`services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => Configuration.Bind("JwtSettings", options)) .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => Configuration.Bind("CookieSettings", options));`

From here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-3.1